# IIS rewrite rule to redirect multiple domains to different apps on same site

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

I am new to IIS rewrite rules and need help with writing rules that will do the following:

**For example:**

https://domain1.com -> redirect to https://domain1.com/Portal

https://dm1.com --> redirect to https://dm1.com/Portal

https://domain2.com --> redirect to https://domain2.com/Client

https://dm2.com --> redirect to https://dm2.com/Client

IIS Site:

Default Web Site

- Portal
- Client

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) You are trying to replace URLs with backslashes? Never seen any such...

Answer (score 0):

if you have few web sites, not just one web site with few bindings, than it could be done by using:

1) HTTP redirect in IIS

2) by using `default.asp` page with `Response.Redirect` command

3) by using `IsapiRewrite` DLL's. `RewriteRule  ^/ /Portal`

4) IIRF (just modern(?) version of `IsapiRewrite`)

even if you have one web site with few bindings it could be done by using method #2 & #3... of course method #2 and #3 must be adjusted in this case.